# How to analyse data from multiple binary decisions?

Tags: binary-data

In an experiments participants will be presented with pairs of sentences and they will have to pick which of the two is closer to the way they would say things (two-alternative forced choice). There will be three types of sentences (let’s call them A, B, and C)
We will generate pairs of sentences pitting each of these patterns against each other (A vs B, A vs C, B vs C) and need to know which of the three patterns is the most accepted one, which one is the second one, etc. with respect to the other ones and whether the differences are significant. All participants will see all pairs of sentences.
What would be the right way to analyze this type of data?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are each person given the three choices A-B, A-C and B-C (for one set of three sentences), or are each person only given a (random?) choice from one of the three pairs? If given all three, in which order, randomized order, for instance, mixed in with other sentences, or the three pairs in succession? We need some more detailed information.

Comment: Each person will be given all three choices interspersed with other sentences (some fillers, some experimental items). The order of presentation of all items will be randomized individually for each participant, as will be the order of presentation of the two options within each item. Please let me know what other relevant details I should add to this description. Thanks for your willingness to help.